# How To Download Dashboard Screenshots Programmatically

Tags: apex, javascript, dashboard

I need to download dashboard images progamatically(apex or javascript). Is there away this can be done?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not possible inside salesforce using apex/javascript because you will have to run that on load of the page. You cannot customize something like onload property on a dashboard page.

A hack :

1. In outlook create a distribution list and add all the users emails to that distribution list
2. Create a user in SF with email as the email of the distribution list
3. Subscribe to the dashboard as this user
4. Screenshot will be sent to this email, which will further received by all users

Alternatively you can also create an outlook rule to forward the email received by any one of the 5 users to all others.

Comment: Yes it makes sense because that's the business requirement. This is a standard salesforce functionality that works by subscribing to a dashboard but the problem is that a user can only subscribe to 5 dashboards. When user subscribes to a dashboard they receive an image of the refreshed dashboard on a scheduled basis.  I need to replicate the same functionality but for more users. thanks

Comment: I have answered your question in second paragraph. What you asked cannot be done using apex/javascript.

Comment: Alright, Thank you.

Comment: This answer could be improved by elaborating on the Visualforce solution and why it is a bad pattern, since it seems to contradict the "not possible" claim.

Comment: Check the latest suggestion